# Reset select border radius on Chrome (Mac)

Tags: html, css, macos

I am trying to reset the `border radius` of `select` tag in chrome (Mac) but its still showing after applying my `CSS`, how do I reset the `border-radius` in chrome (mac), it works fine in windows and fireFox in Mac.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/1uwbgtm9/)

```css
select {
padding: 10px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius:0;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option Title Goes here</option>
  <option>Option Title Goes here</option>
  <option>Option Title Goes here</option>
  <option>Option Title Goes here</option>
  <option>Option Title Goes here</option>
  <option>Option Title Goes here</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to your css, and style select then according to your needs.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: by adding this line, its resetting radius but remove the dropdown arrow that it should not.

Comment: add your own arrow as a background image positioned "right center", I don't think you can just remove border radius alone

Answer (score 2):

This will appear identical to the webkit version but without the border radius. It uses Base64 format for the arrows.

```
select {
    height: 19px;
    padding: 0 14px 0 8px; /* replace native select (has rounded edges on mac) */
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-position: calc(100% - 4px) 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 5px 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    background: url("arrow_image_url");
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Making webkit-appearance "none" will remove the drop arrow as well, which you can set using the background attribute.

Cheers!